# Using pre-compiled Qt5 library in a Qt6 application

Tags: c++, qt, libraries

I'm new to **libraries** and using 3rd party code. I want to ask **simple question** is there any way that I can use a library precomplied and fully compatible with **Qt5** and use it as is **without making any changes** (i.e, fixing the issues/errors or recompiling) in a **Qt6 application** despite the fact that the underlying Qt API has been changed.

If there is a way what should be the actual process?

The library I am using is: **JKQTPlotter**

Comment: I doubt it; Qt6 isn't even source-code compatible with Qt5, so the chances of it being binary-compatible are close to zero.  I think you'd need to recompile the library under Qt6 (and probably it will require some tweaking of the library's source code to get it to compile under Qt6 as well)

Comment: can i use qt5 and qt6 at same time in 1 application

Comment: No; they both declare the same class and function names in the same namespace, so you would get duplicate-symbol-errors from your linker if you tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use that library in any application: the library itself needs Qt 5. Your application doesn't need to.

Then you need a non-Qt bridge between the Qt 6 application and the Qt 5 library.

You can create a dynamic library that exposes the functionality of JKQTPlotter in some agnostic way without using Qt in the interface itself. For example, you could render the plots into `Qt5::QImage`, then have the bridge expose those to your Qt 6 application, where you would create a wrapper `Qt6::QImage` that doesn't own the bitmap, and thus doesn't copy and is thus "free".

Porting JKQTPlotter to Qt 6 is a trivial task though, so it'd be best if you just ported it :)

Comment: ...and how the user would interact with a QImage???